# GPS monitoring in background mode for iOS

Tags: ios, background, gps, monitoring

I want to implement a feature on iOS to notify user when reach a special location (such as a bus station, don't miss it), it is easy if user always put app in foreground mode, using GPS location to detect whether arrived nearly or not. The key point is how to achieve it in background mode.

One possible solution is to update GPS in background mode, something like map navigation APP, but as you know GPS is power killer, user may not like it.

See CoreLocation API, found the following delegate callbacks, I am not sure whether they work well in background mode. Any idea on this topic please share and discuss together and thanks in advance.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7,__IPHONE_4_0);    


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_TBD,__IPHONE_5_0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Location and Maps Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH9-SW5)

> In iOS, regions associated with your app are tracked at all times,
>   including when the app isn’t running. If a region boundary is crossed
>   while an app isn’t running, that app is relaunched into the background
>   to handle the event. Similarly, if the app is suspended when the event
>   occurs, it’s woken up and given a short amount of time (around 10
>   seconds) to handle the event. When necessary, an app can request more
>   background execution time using the
>   beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: method of the UIApplication
>   class.